# In Visual Studio 2012, I get warnings and squiggly lines when trying to write JSX with React JS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reactjs

I am using a separate javascript file to put my React JS JSX in. When I use the example given by the documents, I get tons of Visual Studio warnings and ugly squiggly lines..

I cannot figure out a way around this.. Pretty much a deal breaker for React JS.

[image]

Comment: The way around this is not to use Visual Studio for editing your JSX files, and use a decent IDE/editor like vim, sublime, webstorm, emacs or komodo instead.  All of which support React's JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 was released before ReactJs, so you can't really blame them for not supporting it.

There is some visual studio stuff here:

http://reactjs.net/

You can see support for tooling being asked here:

https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/3

with Web Essentials being one of the prime picks for asking for support (might want to add your votes!)

If you are using Resharper it might be added in the next release, JetBrains is looking to add it into WebStorm

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10136

Comment: I've looked at reactjs.net, but I'm only using html and javascript for this smallish web resource inside CRM. I'm not using Asp.Net.

I think I'll hold off on React JS for now. Thank you for your help John..

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're essentially putting html into your javascript. I found this after a quick google search and might fix your problem: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d65d6b29-6dd7-4100-81b1-609e5afce356

The page mentions: "Visual Studio currently doesn't have native JSX syntax support. You can edit .jsx files in regular VS JavaScript editor for now and vote for adding native JSX support in Visual Studio here (the most requested feature in WE)."

Comment: I have stumbled upon the starter kit, but I'm really only writing one module inside of a CRM application so it would be a bit overkill. Thank you for your suggestion zackify.

I think I'll have to hold off on react js for now.

Comment: I would just ignore it or save my files as .jsx and have no highlighting.

Comment: That would be an accepted solution, but the jsx builder does not build .jsx, it only builds if I change the file back to .js.

jsx --watch src/ build/